# Tail call optimization via translating to CPS

Tags: compilers, recursion, loops, continuations, tail-recursion

I am struggling to wrap my head around this compiler technique, so let's say here's my *`factorial`* function

```python
def factorial(value: int) -> int:
    if value == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return factorial(value-1) * value
```

It is recursive, but not TCO friendly yet, so, as the theory goes, the first thing to try here is translate it to CPS:

```python
def factorial_cont(value: int, cont: typing.Callable[[int], T]) -> T:
    if value == 0:
        return cont(1)
    else:
        return factorial_cont(value-1, lambda result:  cont(value * result))
```

Now, as the function is tail call recursive, I can do the usual trick with the while loop:

```python
def factorial_while(value: int, cont: typing.Callable[[int], T]) -> T:
    current_cont = cont
    current_value = value
    while True:
        if current_value == 0:
            return current_cont(1)
        else:
            current_cont = lambda result: current_cont(current_value * result)
            # note: in actual python that would look like
            # current_cont = lambda result, c=current_cont, v=current_value: c(v * result)
            current_value = current_value - 1
```

This `current_cont` thing effectively becomes a huge composition chain, in `haskell` terms for the `value == 3` that would be `let resulting_cont = ((initial_cont . (3*)) . (2*)) . (1*)`, where `initial_cont` is safe to default to `id`, and surely enough `resulting_cont value == value!`.

But I also know the trick with "`accumulator`" value:

```python
def factorial_acc(value: int, acc: int = 1) -> int:
    current_acc = acc
    current_value = value
    while True:
        if current_value == 1:
            return current_acc
        else:
            current_acc = current_acc * current_value
            current_value = current_value - 1
```

which looks pretty much identical to the CPS version after the introduction of while loop.

The question is, how exactly do I massage the continuation `let resulting_cont = ((initial_cont . (3*)) . (2*)) . (1*)` into the form resembling `accumulator` version?

Answer (score 2):

Somehow turn the opaque lambdas

```python
next_cont = lambda result: current_cont(current_value * result)
```

into transparent data

```ml
next_cont = Compose( current_cont, Mult(current_value))
```

then use the fact that

```ml
 Compose( Compose( a_cont, Mult(val)), Mult(current_value))
==
 Compose( a_cont, Compose( Mult(val), Mult(current_value)))
==
 Compose( a_cont, Mult( val*current_value ))
```

You end up with `Compose( init_cont, Mult( result ))` which you then call with

```ml
 call( Compose( init_cont, Mult( result )), 1 )
=
 init_cont( call( Mult(result), 1)) 
=
 init_cont( result*1 )
```

Look up "reifying continuations" and "defunctionalization".

Comment: also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defunctionalization.